# Upload and retrieve text/pdf/img files on mongodb using mongoose in a MEAN stack application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I've been trying to write a piece of code in which the user creates a dynamic url, uploads a file by clicking on a button on the page, and the user can also download the same file in the same format when he/she visits the same url again. The concept is very much like [cl1p](https://cl1p.net) with a difference of file in place of text.

I worked out a lot of answers on SO but I cannot find any help on how to accept the file in angular *controller*, and pass to the back end(node.js code), where the file can be saved on mongodb database using *mongoose*, and the same file can be retrieved from the mongodb database. Also, I wish to save the complete file in database, not just the path/destination of file.

Please help.

As of now, all I have is -

```
<div ng-controller="main">
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="file" />
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</div>
```

**PS**: Do not ask me to use GridFS, it is useful in cases when data exceeds 16MB, my file size won't exceed 2~3MB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with angular. But, I can give some hint in backend.

**model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
  image: {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
    .
    .
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', schema);
```

**route.js**

```
var Model = require('path/to/model');

// POST: called by uploading form
router.post('/add', function (req, res, next) {

  var model = new Model();

  fs.readFile(req.body.myFile, function (err, data) {

    model.image.data = data;
    // get extension
    model.image.contentType = req.body.myFile.split('.').pop();
        .   
        .
    model.save(function (err, model) {
      if(err) throw err;
      res.status(201).json(model);
    });

  });
});

// GET image by model id: subsequence retrieval
router.get('/:id/image', function (req, res, next) {
  var modelId = req.params.id;
  Model.findById(modelId, function (err, model) {
    res.contentType(model.image.contentType);
    res.json(model.image.data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the second part of the process. I'm still struggling with the controller part. anyways, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

i used https://github.com/expressjs/multer
worked for me, especially if you want to store it anywhere else but a DB later on.

And https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload on the client side if you use Angular 1.